# How to center a button in Html?

Tags: html, css, button, center, text-align

Why can I align this button on html, you normally put a text-align: center a tat all. I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong or what.

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(129,180,30, 0.9); width: 40%; margin-top: 50px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px; text-align:justify">
<h2>Proteger para progresar</h2>
<h5>La condición humana está muy ligada al progreso. En mayor o menor medida, todos queremos progresar en aquellos ámbitos en los que nos centramos en nuestro día a día. Los padres quieren que sus hijos estudien y sean buenas personas para que les vaya bien en la vida.</h5>
<button href="https://mediassegur.com/proteger-para-progresar" style="text-align:center;">Leer mas</button>
</div>
```

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use margin to achieve this.

```css
button {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(129,180,30, 0.9); width: 40%; margin-top: 50px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px; text-align:justify">
<h2>Proteger para progresar</h2>
<h5>La condición humana está muy ligada al progreso. En mayor o menor medida, todos queremos progresar en aquellos ámbitos en los que nos centramos en nuestro día a día. Los padres quieren que sus hijos estudien y sean buenas personas para que les vaya bien en la vida.</h5>
<button href="https://mediassegur.com/proteger-para-progresar">Leer mas</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `button` in one `<div>` and add `text-align:center` in div

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(129,180,30, 0.9); width: 40%; margin-top: 50px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px; text-align:justify">
  <h2>Proteger para progresar</h2>
  <h5>La condición humana está muy ligada al progreso. En mayor o menor medida, todos queremos progresar en aquellos ámbitos en los que nos centramos en nuestro día a día. Los padres quieren que sus hijos estudien y sean buenas personas para que les vaya bien en la vida.</h5>
  <div style="text-align:center;"><button href="https://mediassegur.com/proteger-para-progresar">Leer mas</button></div>
</div>
```